# Disable TLS 1.3 in Twisted Python

Tags: ssl, openssl, twisted, tls1.3

How do I disable TLS 1.3 in a Twisted server?  Here's my code that should disable TLS 1.3, but doesn't:

```
from twisted.internet import ssl

ciphers = ssl.AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString(
    "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA"
)

tls_options = ssl.CertificateOptions(
    privateKey=my_key,
    certificate=my_cert,
    extraCertChain=my_cert_chain,
    acceptableCiphers=ciphers,
    lowerMaximumSecurityTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
)

listening_port = my_reactor.listenSSL(8000, my_factory, tls_options)
```

I added the `lowerMaximumSecurityTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2` but that seems to disable TLS 1.2 (!) and leave TLS 1.3 available.  Here's the results:

```
 SSLv2      not offered (OK)
 SSLv3      not offered (OK)
 TLS 1      offered (deprecated)
 TLS 1.1    offered (deprecated)
 TLS 1.2    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol
 TLS 1.3    offered (OK): final
```

With `lowerMaximumSecurityTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2` removed or changed to `TLSv1_3` then TLS 1, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are all reported as supported.

I'm testing this using testssl.sh 3.1dev from https://testssl.sh/dev/

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 including their packages for Twisted, OpenSSL, Python3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by mixing an old Python OpenSSL package with a modern OpenSSL native library.  Both provided by Ubuntu 18.04.  The fix was to update the Python OpenSSL package, using PIP instead of a system package.

Why this fails:

- The OpenSSL native library enables TLS 1.3 by default.
- The old Python OpenSSL package does not expose the constants needed to turn TLS 1.3 off.
- The modern Twisted checks the OpenSSL Python package, sees that it does not expose the constants needed to turn TLS 1.3 off, and wrongly assumes that the OpenSSL native library does not support TLS 1.3.  It doesn't provide any warnings about this.